# error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct Item’

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-allocation

Here are the relevant structs. Note that they are in the header of the same file.

```
typedef enum {AAA = 0, BBB = 1, CCC = 2, DDD = 3} Subject;

typedef struct item {
    Subject sub;
    int n, h;
    char title[1024];
} Item;

struct Item* Collection = NULL;
```

Inside main, I allocate space for Collection:

```
Collection = malloc(sizeof(Item*));
```

Then I have, inside my main, a switch statement that calls the insert() function That function is below:

```
void course_insert() {
    Collection = realloc(Collection,(sizeof(Collection) + sizeof(Iem)));
    printf("What is the subject? (AAA=0, BBB=1, CCC=2, DDD=3)? ");
    scanf("%u", Collection[count].sub);
    printf("What is the number (e.g 20)? ");
    scanf("%d", Collection[count]->n);
    printf("How many hours (e.g. 3)? ");
    scanf("%d", Collection[count]->h);
    printf("What is the name of the item? ");
    scanf("%s", Collection[count]->title);   
    count++;
}
```

I'm getting a error saying that it's an invalid use of undefined type 'struct Item' but I can use it just fine elsewhere. Can anyone spot what the issue is?

Comment: C is case-sensitive; `struct Item` has not been defined (you only defined `struct item` and `Item`). Also there are several logical errors in the rest of your code

Comment: `Collection = malloc(sizeof(Item*));` --> `Collection = malloc(sizeof(Item));` or `Collection = malloc(sizeof(*Collection));` and so on.

Comment: `scanf("%u", Collection[count].sub);` --> `scanf("%u", &Collection[count].sub);`

Comment: Also `sizeof(Collection)` is pointer size. It isn't the size of the contents pointed to by the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `typedef` statement means `typedef` `struct item` `Item`. This means that you have defined `struct item` and `Item` but not `struct Item`. Try using either of `struct item` or `Item`.